# Bitcoin URGENTLY Need Blocks Files - Download them from some Website

Tags: wallet, blockchain, bitcoin-core, address, block

I have been doing this synchronization procedure (first time) in bitcoin-qt for over 85 hours and it only came to 31 Weeks Behind. Withdrawed from localbitcoins like 95 hours ago and obviously this balance isn't yet seen. I have come to the step where I cannot wait anymore. I only have 512 dram and it is taking my whole system. Also cannot leave pc runned 24/7 anymore. It would be amazing if someone could please upload to some fast legitimate file sharing website like rapidshare.com the blocks files - remaining ones. Once again I repeat i am at 31 Weeks Behind. Or please if you could at least provide me the downloading link if you already shared blocks files yesterday with anyone else or maximum two days ago. I really need that procedure finished please and would owe you for a lifetime for such files so I can just save them. Would be much faster. I cannot use torrents, even if those files are updated enough and already there - torrents aren't safe and could be full of malware.

Answer (score 1):

If you were in such a hurry to get your coins, why didn't you install a light client as Multibit or Electrum? You could've installed either, use the address it generated for the destination address of your withdrawal, and receive your coins after some minutes.

The point of using the original QT client versus any of these is to increase the Bitcoin network's security by creating more copies of the blockchain.

Options you have: just keep going! Seriously, 31 weeks is not that much time, in about another day you could get it finished. Else, you could try the [ordering the blockchain in DVD](http://startbitcoin.com/blockchain-on-dvd/) (I believe there are other sites like that one selling it) or you could try downloading it from a [SourceForge "project"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/) containing them up to a certain point (which I believe you're already past) or [these others](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=19296.0) or any of the other links mentioned at the question which I believe this question's a duplicate of.

Comment: because btc had already been withdrawed by me to existing wallet id before i started to sync it. Electrum has many disadvantages such as not being able to receive funds from users using bitcoin-qt.exe and not being able to send to them also. Too strict amount limits per one transaction. Also Electrum's server can go down at any time. I appreciate your post a lot, thank you very much for it, don't understand me wrong but it is beyond my understanding how is possible you overlooked such basic subject as outdated files on sourceforge before providing it to me? I need uploads of blocks.

Comment: As stated in the other answer, you can import your keys and addresses to either Multibit or Electrum and they'll work as usual. Plus, something must be really wrong with your Electrum installation if it cannot receive/transfer funds to users of bitcoin-qt. Alternate clients exist because the protocol is mostly client-agnostic, I myself use Multibit an have never had problems sending/receiving coins to/from anyone - stopped using bitcoin-qt precisely because of exasperation with the synch process.

Comment: JOE PINEDA you said I am able to receive btc into Electrum sent from bitcoin-qt. You also said I am able to send btc from Electrum into someone's bitcoin-qt. But there are three more problems: FIRST: Is it only FIRST time when opening Electrum that I don't need to do synchronization of blocks or do I NEVER need to do it in Electrum? SECOND: BEFORE (!) I started to do synchonization in bitcoin-qt I had withdrawed from website (in my case localbitcoins.com). Will I for sure get those btc if importing wallet+privatekey? THIRD: Do i have to keep -qt blocks files on hard drive when using electrum?

Comment: 1 & 3: Thin clients do not need to download the blockchain *ever*, so you won't need to keep the -qt block files. They do need to do some synch with their servers each time you open them, but this happens in at most some minutes (usually just seconds).

Comment: But BEFORE (!) I started to do synchonization in bitcoin-qt I had withdrawed from website (in my case localbitcoins.com). Will I for sure get those btc if importing wallet+privatekey? I repeat that I haven't downloaded not even one single block because i withdrawed from website first. Those exact btc might not come to Electrum. It has passed long time (more than 100 hours) since i withdrawed them from localbitcoins.com website.

Comment: 2: Your BTC don't *live* in your physical hard drive, but in the blockchain (with hundreds of distributed copies). You could **theoretically** import your private keys to 100 different machines (running bitcoin-qt or electrum, doesn't matter) and access your funds from each. ***DANGEROUS*** sending some coins from one machine and some others from another could lead to all kinds of trouble since that's not the way it's supposed to work but at least in theory you do can. And just checking your balance from each machine would be 100% safe.

Comment: Since you seem to be in a real hurry and the process of importing the keys isn't very user friendly (involves using the command line and manual steps) you might be better off just waiting or placing this same request at bitcointalk - someone in that community might know of a more recent source of downloadable files. Delivery of DVD could last 1-2 days :(

Comment: hmm well ok, thank you for your time for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about the Electrum client.  From the bitcoin client you can export your private keys, and then import them elsewhere (actually will be COPYING them elsewhere) such as in to the electrum client.  There is not 'an electrum server' it is distributed system and anyone can run a server, private or public; there are many nodes online you can synch to.